# Deploy Lambda Functions in or via Bamboo

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, build, aws-lambda, bamboo

How can we deploy a set of **Lambda functions** using the **Serverless** stack via **Bamboo**? Is there any way to write scripts/tasks to deploy lambda functions or applications in Bamboo?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `AWS Lambda Function task` in Bamboo as shown here:

[image]

The link to the description how to use the task is here:
https://utoolity.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/TAWS/pages/50004002/Using+the+AWS+Lambda+Function+task+in+Bamboo

A description of deploying the lambda function is here:
https://utoolity.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/TAWS/pages/50003999/Deploying+to+AWS+Lambda

Comment: This seems to require a license. Is that correct, or is something free available?

Answer (score 0):

If the aws lambda is written in node.js, you can directly add a node js task and include your script files or even write script inline in tasks. If written using C#, you can use MS build tasks to deploy the same. I have used both of them. You can find the Node js or MS build in Atlassian marketplace. If its not suitable, you can write your own using java and deploy.